# If I want my graphql endpoint to be something other than `/graphql`, how do I configure it with the `GraphqlModule`?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I have this code below in my `main.ts`:

```
const server = express();
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server));
app.listen(9000);
```

Also in my `AppModule` imports I have this:

```
GraphQLModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => config.get('graphql'),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

And then I access my graphql endpoint at the address `http://localhost:9000/graphql`. My question is how can I change my graphql endpoint to a different url, say: `http://localhost:9000/whatever`? Is the `/graphql` internally configured by default or is it specified somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the graphql endpoint in the module options with the key `path`:

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
  // ...
  path: '/mygraphql',
}),
```

or in your case respectively in the config provided by your `ConfigService`.